# How can I stack 20 "plate" looking objects (ellipse shape) to 20 with if or while statements? My functions are not working correctly

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to code in java a 20 plate stack using a key pressed function to stack a new plate and a mouse click function to make the individual plates disappear one by one to 0. I cannot figure out why my functions won't work they will not do as I command them, please help.

```
 // Declare global (shared) variables here
 float plate1X = 50;
 float plate1Y = 200;
 int plateCount = 20;


 // Do not write any statements here (must be inside methods)


   // Add statements to run once when program starts here.  For example:
  void setup() { 
   size(400,400);
   plate1X = 200;
   plate1Y = 50;
   background(255);
   plate1X = width/2;
   plate1Y = height-25;



 } // end of setup method


 void draw()
 {
   // Declare local variables here (new each time through)

   // Add statements to run each time screen is updated here
   ellipse(plate1X, plate1Y, 200,50);
   stroke(0);
   fill(50,100,40);
 }





   // Screen will be repainted automatically at the end of draw method
    // end of draw method

 // Add other methods here  
 void keyPressed() {
   plate1Y = -25;
   while( plate1Y < height) 
     ellipse(plate1X, plate1Y, 200,50);

     plate1Y = plate1Y - 10;
   }
   void mousePressed() {
     while( plate1Y <= -205)
     ellipse(plate1X, plate1Y, 200,50);

     plate1Y = plate1Y + 10;
   }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this? Are you getting an error (if so, what), or is the output different from what you expected (if so, how)?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? It looks like you are using Processing. You don't actually appear to have implemented anything you stated in your requirements. For example, I see no `mouseClicked()`, I see no usage of `plateCount`, etc. You'll have to make at least some effort. Your code is doing precisely as you commanded it to do.

Comment: *they will not do as I command them* No-one can help unless you explain exactly what you expected and how the actual output differs from that. We are not mind readers and nor is the compiler.

Comment: I think part of your problem is that ellipse, stroke, and fill have no definitions.

Comment: @HotLicks Well, they do in Processing (and don't need to be in an explicit class in that case; responding to your future comment); which, as an educated guess, I'd say he's using here. I added the tag even though he didn't state it, but confidence is high.

Comment: And also, your code needs to be inside a class.  And likely that class needs to be a subclass of some other class.

Comment: This is actually a processing question, I've removed the java tag.

Comment: I got the keyPressed function to stack plates but the mouseClick or press function will not subtract plates, that is where I am at with this code..any ideas?

Comment: @Salixalba Well, a Processing question is technically a Java question; Processing is just an API, and they happen to also provide an IDE that just plops your code into a Java source file. All Java syntax and JDK objects still apply. So, unless it's specifically related to Processing's IDE, I believe it also falls under Java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw each plate every time the `draw()` method is called, this typically happens 60 times a second. You might keep the coordinated of each plate in two arrays `plateX[]` and  `plateY[]` with `numPlates` keeping track of how many plates there are. You can add or subtract entries to the array in you `keyPressed()` and `mousePressed()` methods, but don't do any actual drawing there.

```
// Declare global (shared) variables here
 float plate1X = 50;
 float plate1Y = 200;
 int plateCount = 20;

int numPlates = 1;
float plateX[] = new float[plateCount];
float plateY[] = new float[plateCount];

 // Do not write any statements here (must be inside methods)


   // Add statements to run once when program starts here.  For example:
  void setup() { 
   size(400,400);
   background(255);
   plate1X = width/2;
   plate1Y = height-25;
   plateX[0]=plate1X;
   plateY[0]=plate1Y;


 } // end of setup method


 void draw()
 {
   // Declare local variables here (new each time through)

   // Add statements to run each time screen is updated here
   for(int i=0;i<numPlates;++i)
    ellipse(plateX[i], plateY[i], 200,50);
   stroke(0);
   fill(50,100,40);
 }

   // Screen will be repainted automatically at the end of draw method
    // end of draw method

 // Add other methods here  
 void keyPressed() {
   plate1Y -= 25;
   if( plate1Y > 0) {
   plateX[numPlates]=plate1X;
   plateY[numPlates]=plate1Y;
     ++numPlates;
   }
 }   
  void mousePressed() {
     --numPlates;
     plate1Y += 25;
   }
```